# How to insert multiple records using one query if the number of repetitions are different from each other

Tags: php, mysql

I'm really confused about how to insert data into the table using one query when you've different **number** of items that are you trying to insert.

I'm thinking of the table should look like this.

**TABLE**

`day`     `start`     `startGrams`     `breakfast`      `breakfastGrams`

**Example**:

Consider this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6uPq.png)

In the image the user would able to enter grams for the food items for different days,from the front end side.

On maandag (Monday) at **START**, let say user has entered grams for `whey protein` and `water`.
and on the same day i.e `monday` let he want to enter **BREAKFAST** grams only for `water`.

How many time should I run the insert query because in the first I've to insert grams for 2 food items and then for `one` food item.

I'm assuming to grab all the `grams` fields and then insert into the table through one query.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: why do you want to do it in one query?

Comment: @kuh-chan Why wouldn't you?

Comment: what else I could do ? @kuh-chan

Comment: @Strawberry I'd make a prepared insert and run a loop over the post data to insert them with parameter binding

Comment: Redesign your table.

Comment: @kuh-chan please let me know via psudo code .

Comment: Without fixing your design, this is a hopeless course of action.

Comment: What should I do with my table ? @strawberry

Comment: this is just a part, I've all kind of lunch,dinner,Morning and evening snack and their grams respectively at each particular day, how should I design the table @strawberry

Comment: @Nprogrammer have a look at the docs - http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php , there are useful examples. But Strawberry is right - you should redesign you tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer; too long for a comment...

A normalised schema *might* look something like this. Note that there is likely further scope for normalisation, but it's a start...

```
schedule
day     session   meal_id
monday  start           1
monday  breakfast       1
tuesday start           1
tuesday breakfast       1


meal_detail
meal_id ingredient_id quantity unit
      1           101       80   gr
      1           102       30   gr
      1           103      118   gr
      1           104       24   gr
      1           105       21   gr
      1           100      237   gr

ingredients
ingredient_id name
          100 water (1 cup)
          101 havermout 
          102 whey protein
          103 banaan (1 med.)
          104 pindakaas 
          105 honing (1 tl)
```

Comment: I'm sure this will help me a lot, @strawberry thank you so much !